# unable to populate fields using $ctrl in view with AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, rest, angular-ui-router

Using `ui-router`, and I am resolving data so it is available to my view before it renders, like so:

```
.state('app.userprofile', {
        url: '/userprofile',
        component: 'user',
        resolve: {
            user: ['userService', function(userService) {
                return userService.fetchUser();
            }],
            timezones: ['timezoneService', function(timezoneService){
                return timezoneService.fetchUsaTimeZones();
            }]
        }
    })
}]);
```

If I log to the console from my `state`, it shows the response:

```
resolve: {
   user: ['userService', function(userService) {
      return userService.fetchUser().then(function(response){console.log(response)};
    }]
```

[image]

I am trying to populate the fields within my `user-profile.htm`, which is specified in the `user component`, using the default controllerAs reference `$ctrl`. I have used this throughout my app but for some reason within this state it is failing to accomplish this.

***Question***

Why are my fields failing to load data provided by the model?

```
app.component('user', {
    bindings: { user: '<' },
    bindings: { timezones: '<' },
    templateUrl: 'p3sweb/app/components/user/views/user-profile.htm',
    controller: ['userService', 'timezoneService', function(userService, timezoneService) {

        var vm = this;

     //functinality for updating user

    }]
});

app.factory('userService', function($http, $q) {

    var factory = {};

        var REST_SERVICE_URI = 'http://localhost:8080/p3sweb/rest-user/';

        factory.fetchUser = function() {

            var deferred = $q.defer();
             $http.get(REST_SERVICE_URI)
                .then(
                function (response) {
                    deferred.resolve(response.data);
                },
                function(errResponse){
                    console.error('Error while fetching user');
                    deferred.reject(errResponse);
                }
            );

            return deferred.promise;
        }

    return factory;

});
```

---

```
<form  action="#" method="POST" name="userProfileForm">
    <div>
        <legend >User Info</legend>
        <div class="form-group row">
            <label for="emailAddress">Email address</label>
            <div>
                <input type="email" name="emailAddress" ng-model="$ctrl.user.emailAddress">

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: 'bindings' can be collated into one; bindings: { user: '<', timezones: '<' } could be possible the second one is overwriting the first; also where are you actually embedding the <user /> in your html?

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out, not sure why I did that, but unfortunately that wasn't the issue. My components are my entire html and are loaded through `ui-router` `<ui-view>`

Comment: @rrd, you were right! Please write it as an answer and I will mark it as correct. Stupid error on my behalf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the bindings, the second one is overwriting the first:

```
bindings: {
  user: '<',
  timezones: '<'
}
```

That should fix it :)

Comment: Thanks again for your time!

Comment: Happy to have helped!